# PhantomJS cannot visit Self-signed HTTPS pages Codeception

Tags: selenium, ssl, phantomjs, codeception

Im currently making an acceptance test with the following tools:

- Codeception
- Selenium Webdriver
- PhantomJS *(as headless browser ghost)*

My problem is **My Tests fail when visiting a self-signed (https) page**

What I've tried:

1. `phantomjs --webdriver=5555 --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any`
2. Adding this in capabilities `phantomjs.cli.args: ["--ignore-ssl-errors=true"]` in my acceptance.suit.yml

So far these options doesnt give me any luck.

Here is my `acceptance.suit.yml` file

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: https://myproject.com
            browser: firefox
            capabilities:
                unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'

env:
    phantom:
        modules:
            enabled:
                - WebDriver
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    url: https://myproject.com
                    http_proxy: 192.1.1.1
                    http_proxy_port: 3000
                    browser: phantomjs
                    capabilities:
                        phantomjs.cli.args: ["--ignore-ssl-errors=true"]
```

**UPDATE**

This error shows up `[ModuleException] WebDriver: Current url is blank, no page was opened`

I don't know why this error happens since I've indicated a page. Here is a sample of my test

```
public function tryToTestThis(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo('Test this function');
    $I->amOnPage('/mypage/');
    $I->see('This text');
}
```

An answer in Codeception would be preferable. Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what is happening? Any errors, how does the test fail? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Hi I updated my post. It says `[ModuleException] WebDriver: Current url is blank, no page was opened`

Comment: I was able to replicate your error and running phantomjs with --ignore-ssl-errors=true enabled my test to pass. Only difference is I'm not using http_proxy and http_proxy_port, have you checked your proxy?

Comment: @MajicBob Yes I've made sure my proxy is right. What Im not sure is, if its the right way to set the `http_proxy` codeception doesnt show any example that is setting an `http_proxy` and `http_proxy_port`

Comment: @Þaw Yeah the docs aren't great there and I haven't used it with a proxy before. The only other things I can think of are to make sure you are seeing the request come in to your proxy and try moving the 2 settings to the modules: section instead of env.

Comment: When you have a proxy in the mix, your proxy has to accept the certificate on your behave first.  So The problem may be with your proxy.  How are you managing your proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out the cause if this problem. It was because I was running `Selenium` and `phantomJS` at the same time. (I got this idea from some tutorial.)

I was doing

```
java -jar selenium.jar
```

then I do this since it causes an error running phantomjs at port 4444 (Obviously selenium is using it) I use port 5555 instead.

```
phantomjs --webdriver=5555 --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any
```

Note: Everything works fine if not involved with https / ssl self-signed pages.

We think that `codeception` prioritize port 4444 and disregarding any option indicated in my phantomjs i.e. `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any` thats why in fails to visit https/self-signed pages.

So basically, the fix was just running phantomjs alone without selenium.

```
phantomjs --webdriver=4444 --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any
```

Thank you